# Redirect a Blogger Page URL to wordpress

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, redirect, htaccess

I have migrated from blogger to wp. And so far, I've solved most of my 404 errors and redirection issues but there is still one problem. A several pages from blogger got indexed by Google and they are my top traffic resources. However, they were pages on blogger, so it looked like this: domainname.com/p/pagename

but wordpress does not accept the /p/. So those old pages opens 404 pages for visitors. I want to redirect them from domainname.com/p/pagename to domainname.com/p-pagename

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Got myself a solution so I will keep it for those who face the same issue.

I added this line to .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 /p/blog-page_21.html http://www.domainname.com/p-blog-page_21
```